# phpunit and autoloader

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, autoload

I'm trying to use autoloader with phpunit this way:

- in phpunit.xml I put `bootstrap="bootstrap.php"`
- in bootstrap.php I put

  ```
  define( 'TESTING', true );
  putenv( 'APPLICATION_ENV=testing' );


  function __autoload($className) {    
      include_once __autoloadFilename($className);
  }


  function __autoloadFilename($className) {
      return str_replace('_','/',$className).".php";
  }
  ```

When trying to run phpunit command i get error:

```
Generating code coverage report, this may take a moment.
Fatal error: Method PEAR_Autoloader::__call() must take exactly 2 arguments in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Autoloader.php on line 211
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I see two functions here but I don't see them getting called anywhere, and neither use the PEAR_Autoloader class.  I don't think the problem is in this section of code.  Work backwards and fine where the PEAR_Autoloader::__call() method is being used.

Comment: Solved? Check this: http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=4426&edit=3